# Eclipse: load my own JAR file before an Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, jar

I want to use the latest version of [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/) in my Google App Engine project.  My project uses GWT plugins, which provide their own, older version of org.json, so if I put my `json.jar` file into `WEB-INF/lib` it gets ignored.  If I go to the Eclipse project's `Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries` to remove the GWT JDK jar the project won't compile.  If I use the same properties tab to add my own `json.jar` to the list of libraries (via `Add Jars...`) it doesn't help.

Is there anything I can do, or am I stuck with the older version of org.json?

**EDIT**: I'm not using Maven.

Comment: If you are using Maven you can specify the exact version of org.json library in your pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

GWT no longer uses `org.json` since 2.7, so all you'd have to do is use an up-to-date version.

That said, even with GWT 2.6.1 or older, you should be able to:

- compile against your more recent version of `org.json` by putting it above the GWT JDK in `Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export`
- run with your more recent version of `org.json` by putting into `WEB-INF/lib`. If that's not enough, you'll maybe have to remove `gwt-servlet-deps.jar` (which contains `org.json` classes) and replace it with `validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar`. That however will only with GWT 2.6; with an even-older version you're out of luck (but 2.6.0 is almost 2 years old already, and 2.5.0 3 years old, that's an eternity at web scale)